# zsh-autosuggestions: Get Next/Previous suggestion

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

When using [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions), is it possible to see more than one suggestion by rolling to the next/previous suggestion? i.e. if I type:

```
ls
```

I might get `ls -l` as a suggestion - is there a keyboard shortcut to view another suggestion (Similar to the way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> are working)?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered once `zsh-autosuggestions` will bring up the first match you can scroll through history:

- scroll-up using <kbd>↑</kbd>
- after first scrolling-up you can scroll-down using <kbd>↓</kbd>
- accept the suggestion with <kbd>→</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can press the right button first, then use the keyboard up and down keys to switch, but did not find the ability to list